# Importar variables de entorno de un .env a un fichero YAML

Tags: aws, lambda, yaml, environment

Estoy investigando y haciendo pruebas sin éxito para importar mis variables de un fichero **.env** a un archivo **template.yaml**. ¿Es posible esto sin acudir a herramientas externas? Estoy trabajando con **AWS SAM**

.env:

```
PORT=8080
```

template.yaml:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
    lambda-data-dictionary-read

    Sample SAM Template for lambda-data-dictionary-read

Globals:
    Function:
        Timeout: 0

Resources:
    IndexFunction:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
        Properties:
            CodeUri: .
            Handler: index.lambdaHandler
            Runtime: nodejs16.x
            Architectures:
                - x86_64
            Environment:
                Variables:
                    PORT: !Ref ${{ PORT }}
            Events:
                Index:
                    Type: Api
                    Properties:
                        Path: /
                        Method: get
        Metadata:
            BuildMethod: esbuild
            BuildProperties:
                Minify: true
                Target: 'es2020'
                Sourcemap: true
                UseNpmCi: true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS no tiene herramientas para lo que pretendes. Tampoco puedes usar las variables de entorno directamente en el stack porque dicho stack no lo procesa tu sistema sino cloudformation, y en ese servicio no existen tus variables de entorno.

Lo que puedes hacer es cargar esas variables de entorno en tu sesión (si no lo has hecho ya) y montar el stack desde la consola de comandos.

Lo primero que hay que hacer es identificar las variables que se quieran importar en el stack. Para cada una de ellas hay que crear un parámetro de entrada:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'

Parameters:
  HTTP_PORT:
    Type: String
    Description: Http Port
```

Después usas los parámetros allí donde los necesites:

```
Resources:
  IndexFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: .
      Handler: index.lambdaHandler
      Runtime: nodejs16.x
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      Environment:
            Variables:
                PORT: !Ref HTTP_PORT
```

Y ahora ya solo queda crear el stack por línea de comandos. Aquí sí que podemos usar las variables de entorno.

```
aws cloudformation deploy \
  --stack-name "Mi_Stack" \
  --template-file archivo.yml \
  --parameter-overrides \
      HTTP_PORT="${PORT}" \
      ...
```

Comment: Gracias por la pronta y clara respuesta eferion. Me ha servido para entender mejor cómo funciona esta herramienta. Opté por utilizar esta sugerencia que me haz recomendado.